# Linearly spaced values between the minimum and maximum values of each column. -Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Much like the title eludes to, im trying to adjust sizes in a skugroup based on knowing the largest and smallest value for each dimension. (L, W, H, V).

The code below i have written and have working but only for one skugroup seen below. Shoe values that were NaN are factored up to their respective sizes based on size order.

Skusizes can be numeric or non-numeric hence my creation of the sorting order, but something isnt sticking and I can seem to figure it out. ID-10T?

```
data_wm = {
    'sku': [6124, 7343, 7981, 5761, 1570, 7223, 4107, 8187, 4653, 1802, 4079],
    'skugroup': ['shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt'],
    'size': ['s', 'm', 'l', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'length': [1.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4],
    'width': [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
    'height': [2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6],
    'volume': [6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 144, 6, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 120]
}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data_wm)
 
def fill_nulls_based_on_size(df):
    for skugroup, group_df in df.groupby('skugroup'):
        min_size = group_df['size'].min()
        max_size = group_df['size'].max()
 
        if pd.to_numeric(min_size, errors='coerce') is not None and pd.to_numeric(max_size, errors='coerce') is not None:
            factorized_size = sorted(group_df['size'], key=lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else float('inf'))
        else:
            size_order = ['s', 'm', 'l', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl']
            factorized_size = size_order
 
        for col in ['length', 'width', 'height', 'volume']:
            factorized_values = pd.Series(np.linspace(min(group_df[col]), max(group_df[col]), len(group_df), endpoint=True))
            df.loc[group_df.index, col] = df.loc[group_df.index, col].fillna(factorized_values)
 
fill_nulls_based_on_size(df)
 
df
```

this is dummy data trying to flesh out my logic, but needs scalability for new skugroups that could be inserted in the future (pants, bag, hat etc.)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can create an ordered [`CategoricalDType`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html) to interpolate values:

```
# You probably know how to create ordered size 1 -> 20, xs -> 4xl, etc
num_size = np.arange(1, 20).astype(str).tolist()
txt_size = ['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl', '4xl']

# The key here is to create an ordered set
sizes = pd.CategoricalDtype(txt_size + num_size, ordered=True)

# Compute linear interpolation
cols = ['length', 'width', 'height', 'volume']
df[cols] = (df.astype({'size': sizes}).sort_values('size')
              .groupby('skugroup', sort=False)[cols]
              .transform(lambda x: x.interpolate()))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     sku skugroup size  length  width  height  volume
0   6124    shoes    s    1.50   2.00    2.00     6.0
1   7343    shoes    m    2.40   3.20    2.20    33.6
2   7981    shoes    l    3.30   4.40    2.40    61.2
3   5761    shoes   xl    4.20   5.60    2.60    88.8
4   1570    shoes  2xl    5.10   6.80    2.80   116.4
5   7223    shoes  3xl    6.00   8.00    3.00   144.0
6   4107    shirt    1    1.00   2.00    3.00     6.0
7   8187    shirt    2    1.75   2.75    3.75    34.5
8   4653    shirt    3    2.50   3.50    4.50    63.0
9   1802    shirt    4    3.25   4.25    5.25    91.5
10  4079    shirt    5    4.00   5.00    6.00   120.0

>>> sizes
CategoricalDtype(categories=['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', '2xl', '3xl', '4xl', '1', '2',
                  '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                  '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19'],
, ordered=True, categories_dtype=object)
```